# Can I import the account from MyEtherWallet to other wallets?

Tags: wallets, accounts, myetherwallet, private-key, keystore

I generated a password protected Ethereum account on MyEtherWallet with the <kbd>Create New Wallet</kbd> button. If MyEtherWallet stops working, will I be able to access this account using another software or other online wallets?

Answer (score 1):

On wallet creation, MEW prompts you to save a keystore file. You can import this file to other wallets and access your funds.